# Datadog agent opentelemetry log ingest

Tags: .net, datadog, open-telemetry

I am sending metrics and traces to a DD agent through opentelemetry otel exporter to the GRPC endpoint. This setup however, is not working for logs. My configuration:

```cs
builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(ops =>
{
    ops.IncludeScopes = true;
    ops.ParseStateValues = true;
    ops.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
    ops.AddOtlpExporter(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Endpoint = new Uri("localhost:4317");
    });
});
```

Then, I am using the `ILogger<T>` instances to log information. Why is that not sent to DD?

Answer (score 4):

DD Agent currently doesn't support OTLP logs. The OTLP intake of the DD agent only works for metrics & traces. We are working on expanding the support to Logs.

Comment: "we"? You happen to own the log support?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with DataDog, so I cannot be sure if this is a DataDog specific issue. However, working backwards, here's how I would approach troubleshooting this issue:

### Validate telemetry reaches your collector

It appears you are sending data from your application through an OpenTelemetry Collector hosted at `localhost:4317`. You can configure the collector with the [Logging Exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/exporter/loggingexporter/README.md) to validate that telemetry emitted from your app is reaching your local collector.

Using this minimal configuration for your collector, logs that are successfully exported from your application and reach the collector will be written to stdout. If you see logs, then this confirms that you have configured the .NET SDK correctly, and your issue is likely with configuring the collector to export to DataDog.

```yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:

exporters:
  logging:
    verbosity: detailed

service:
  pipelines:
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging]
```

### Validate the .NET SDK is configured correctly

If you did not see any logs written to stdout in the previous step, then the .NET SDK may not be configured correctly.

The [.NET SDK has a self-diagnostics feature](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/tree/main/src/OpenTelemetry#self-diagnostics) you can enable in order to troubleshoot any configuration issues. Try enabling it, and review the logs for any errors.

Looking at the code you've provided, one potential issue is that you have not specified a scheme in the endpoint you've configured. `localhost:4317` should be `http://localhost:4317`. Otherwise, your application will fail to start and you'll receive an exception like "Endpoint URI scheme is not supported. Currently only "http" and "https" are supported."